# Entity Framework ID properties

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have an third party class model (that can't be modified) and I need to persist it using EF. The problem is that some classes of that model don't have an ID property and don't have any property that can be used as keys for generated tables using Fluent API.

I also thought to define ID properties in partial classes but partial classes can't be on different assemblies, so that solution is not feasible. Reflection cross my mind but I don't think can be possible.

There is a way (using Fluent API or other technique) to add properties (auto incremental for example) to an existence model that can't be modified?

Comment: Have you tried using these models as base classes for your own models with ID properties?

Comment: The model is BIG, so I have to wrap a LOT of classes with a lot of effort in the conversion. That approach should works but what about another approach to carry less wrapping-conversions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless the 3rd party class is `sealed` you should be able to use it as a base class, and derive a more friendly class from it.  For instance:

```
public class Foo //3rd party class
{ ... }

public class myFoo : Foo
{
    public long FooId {get; set;}
}
```

If it IS `sealed` you can still write a wrapper around it

```
public sealed class Foo //3rd party sealed class
{ ... }

public class FooWrapper
{
    public long FooId {get; set;}
    public Foo InnerFoo {get; set;} 
}
```

In either case, you can then persist your custom object (the derived class or the wrapper) to your DB and then extract the original `Foo` whenever you desire.

**EDIT**
Based on your comment, you could also investigate using Composite Keys.  Frankly, I've never used them in EF, so I wouldn't even really know where to begin telling you about them, but they may be a better fit for your specific needs.

Comment: The second approach will not work for the same reason: "Foo" class don't have an ID property, so EF can't persists table "Foo" and can't relate it with table "FooWrapper". The first approach can work if I create and use the model in my application but is not the case because my application only calls one method of the third party model and that method creates all model using its own classes ("Foo" class among others) and not my classes ("myFoo" class in this case).

Comment: In that scenario you're not persisting your `Foo` class.  You're persisting your `FooWrapper`, which happens to contain a `Foo`.  You would probably have to define the specific map from your `FooWrapper` to your DB.  In all likelihood, the derived class or a composite key will work better in your specific scenario.

Comment: Composite keys can work in some cases but not in others, e.g. dates. The model have a class for dates with only three fields: day, month, and year. The composite key with all three members is an idea but the problem arrive at runtime when EF tries to insert a record already existent in the table.

Comment: Yes, should work but the effort is BIG to coding the mapping, the model have dozens of classes each one with dozens of properties. What about another approach that carry less mapping code?

Comment: Then I declare that that model smells.  Also, you might double-check some assumptions.  There are only `n` dates in all of time, and you're dealing with a small subset of that.  Why have a table which defines a date as only d/m/yyyy (and each as a different column?)?  And why break that into a separate table?  You might not need to persist all that data (which limits what you have to map).

Comment: Are the 3rd party classes `sealed`?

Comment: I appreciate your effort to help and this is very good from you (idea storm). I'm not fan of that model but I can't do anything about that, is a third party model that I should use. They decided to have their own date class with that structure; for things like that EF can't work nice in this case. Classes are not sealed.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42052/discussion-between-alleng-and-rsotolongo)